# image overlay widget Wordpress Jupiter

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

The Widget-Area now looks like that:

[image: You can check the code here: http://neuronade.com/kopie-sdfsdf-3/]

And I would like to have it like that and dont know what Styles I could use to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Please add your css / html code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use Z-index
the element with the larger z index value is going to be on top

for example :

```
<style> 
.a{
position-relative;
left:100px;
z-index:1;
}
.b{position-relative;
z-index:2;
}
</style>
```

here .b would be on top
and z-index values must have a position specified or they wont work